# How do you install RDesktop on Chromebook?

Tags: debian, remote-desktop, chrome-book, chrome-os, rdesktop

I have an HP Chromebook x360 with a Linux Virtual Environment (Debian 11 Bullseye) that I want to connect to my Windows XP. While I do like the Chromebook for that is, I do not like the in-built keyboard and I do not have a USB-C Docking Station to connect it to a monitor. I wanted to try to create a remote connection from XP to my Linux Virtual Environment and vice versa. Unfortunately, I had tried some methods from Remmina to NoMachine but none have failed.

I want to play games and create some video captures from those games. I know that the Chromebook and Windows XP are not ideal for gaming and video captures.I do not have the money now to afford a newer computer si I have to make due with Chromebook. Also, my Windows XP is connected to a LAN via a network cable while my Chromebook is wireless. Interestingly enough when I used NoMachine, it was able to see my Chromebook although it could not connect to my Linux Virtual Environment. I was hoping to install RDesktop to my XP OS remotely.

I had heard some great things about it but I have no idea if it will work for my virtual environment. Can anyone help me install RDesktop on Chromebook? Can anyone help me with this process of Remote Desktop? And networking with between Windows XP and Linux?